# Как после callback заново ввести текст?

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telegram

Есть бот, в него пользователь пишет своё имя. После бот уточняет правильность имени (**yes** или **no**). Если пользователь нажимает **yes**, юзеру просто выдаёт сообщение. А как сделать чтобы после нажатия кнопки **no**, юзер мог заново ввести имя?

````py
from telebot import types
import telebot
bot = telebot.TeleBot("Токен")

reghelper = telebot.types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(True)
reghelper.row("Регистрация")


pname = ""
print("Bot started")
@bot.message_handler(commands=["start"])
def start_message(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Привет, зарегистрируйся", reply_markup = reghelper)

@bot.message_handler(content_types = ["text"])
def get_text_messages(message):
    if message.text.lower() == "регистрация":
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Введите ваше имя: ", reply_markup = reghelper)
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, get_name)

def get_name(message):
    global pname
    pname = message.text
    keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    keyboard.row(  
        telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton("Да", callback_data = "yes"),  
        telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton("Нет", callback_data = "no"))
    question = "Ваше имя: {0}".format(pname)
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, text = question, reply_markup = keyboard)

@bot.callback_query_handler(func = lambda call: True)
def callback_worker(call):
    if call.data == "yes":
        bot.edit_message_text(chat_id = call.message.chat.id, message_id = call.message.message_id, text = "Отлично", parse_mode = "Markdown")
    elif call.data == "no":
        pass
        # Тут нужно чтобы пользователь сразу ввёл своё имя

bot.polling(none_stop = True, interval = 0)```
````

Comment: @ClarkDevlin Я только начал изучать telebot, не могли бы подсказать где и как их использовать в данном случае?

Answer (score 0):

```
from telebot import types
import telebot
bot = telebot.TeleBot("Токен")

reghelper = telebot.types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(True)
reghelper.row("Регистрация")


pname = ""
print("Bot started")
@bot.message_handler(commands=["start"])
def start_message(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Привет, зарегистрируйся", reply_markup = reghelper)

@bot.message_handler(content_types = ["text"])
def get_text_messages(message):
    if message.text.lower() == "регистрация" or message.text.lower() == "Нет":
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Введите ваше имя: ", reply_markup = reghelper)
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, get_name)

def get_name(message):
    global pname
    pname = message.text
    keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    keyboard.row(  
        telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton("Да", callback_data = "yes"),  
        telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton("Нет", callback_data = "no"))
    question = "Ваше имя: {0}".format(pname)
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, text = question, reply_markup = keyboard)

@bot.callback_query_handler(func = lambda call: True)
def callback_worker(call):
    if call.data == "yes":
        bot.edit_message_text(chat_id = call.message.chat.id, message_id = call.message.message_id, text = "Отлично", parse_mode = "Markdown")
    elif call.data == "no":
        get_text_messages(call.message)
```

Comment: Не совсем то что нужно. В данном случае после нажатия на кнопку **no** первое имя переходит в функцию _get_text_messages_, а там у меня стоит проверка на "регистрация". А нужно чтобы после нажатия **no** пользователь вводил имя.

Comment: поэтому я и добавил изменение в условие после слова регистрация.

Comment: Поле нажатия кнопки **no** вылезает ошибка

Comment: замени строку с условием на это     if message.text.lower() == "регистрация" or message.text.lower() == "нет":
т.к. я не учел, что там .lower()